# Postfix Error on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am following this Ubuntu tutorial for installing postfix onto my server: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto

Everything is OK until I get the sending a test email.  I copy and paste the suggested text, and then press enter to get to a new line so that I can enter the `.` on a new line, per the instructions.  After that I keep getting the following error:

```
421 4.3.0 collect: Cannot write ./dfp79Kv5DF023853 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=111): N       o such file or directory
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Sendmail** error. This is **not** Postfix! You are connecting to some other server but not the server running Postfix.